# How to unit test a function with gin context while initializing all dependencies through docker?

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-gin

I am running my main function ,intializing database ,routers through docker then performing unit test for this particular api (masterController) which is a long code so not pasting it here.The problem that i am facing is that i am initializing all my dependencies while running docker but when i'm testing this function they are not initialized like for example it is giving panic on line 31 where i'm using logger which was initialized at the time of running docker and i can't include all my dependencies in my unit test.

```
func TestMasterController(t *testing.T) {

    gin.SetMode(gin.TestMode)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    ctx, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(w)

    ctx.Request = &http.Request{
        URL:    &url.URL{},
        Header: make(http.Header),
    }

    param := map[string]interface{}{
    "some_data":" "
    }

    MockJsonPost(ctx, param)

    MasterController(ctx)
    fmt.Println("inside test function")
    assert.EqualValues(t, http.StatusOK, w.Code)
}


func MockJsonPost(c *gin.Context, content interface{}) {
    c.Request.Method = "POST" // or PUT
    c.Request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    jsonbytes, err := json.Marshal(content)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // the request body must be an io.ReadCloser
    // the bytes buffer though doesn't implement io.Closer,
    // so you wrap it in a no-op closer
    c.Request.Body = io.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(jsonbytes))
}



func MasterController(c *gin.Context) {
    logger.Primary.Trace("enter MasterController")
    defer logger.Primary.Trace("exit MasterController")

    var reqBody dtos.EntryExitRequestBody
    response := dtos.EntryExitResponseBody{
        Status: modelConstant.ControllerResponseStatusFailure,
        Event:  modelConstant.UnsuccessfulDatabaseFetch,
    }
    defer logger.Primary.Debugf("responseBody MasterController: %+v", &response)

    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&reqBody); err != nil {
        logger.Primary.Errorf("error parsing reqBody: %v", err)
        response.Event = modelConstant.UnsuccessfulParse
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, response)
        go sentry.CaptureException(fmt.Errorf("error parsing request body, error: %v", err))
        return
    }

    logger.Primary.Debugf("requestBody MasterController: %+v", reqBody)

//more code

}
```

In mastercontroller first of all i am doing should bind json then using that data for further process.
getting panic --
Output --

```
 === RUN   TestMasterController
 --- FAIL: TestMasterController (0.00s)
 panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
        panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
 [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x7842b9]

goroutine 26 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1.2({0xbf7a80, 0x128bcf0})
        /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1389 +0x24e
testing.tRunner.func1()
        /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1392 +0x39f
panic({0xbf7a80, 0x128bcf0})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:838 +0x207
github.com/sirupsen/logrus.(*Entry).Log(0x0?, 0x0?, {0xc000651ad8?, 0x0?, 0x0?})
        /home/lenevo/go/pkg/mod/github.com/sirupsen/logrus@v1.8.1/entry.go:292 +0x19
github.com/sirupsen/logrus.(*Entry).Trace(...)
        /home/lenevo/go/pkg/mod/github.com/sirupsen/logrus@v1.8.1/entry.go:298
pms/controller/master.MasterController(0xc00011c400)
        /home/lenevo/Desktop/parkplus/parkplus-pms/controller/master/master.go:31 +0x7c
pms/controller/master.TestMasterController(0x0?)
        /home/lenevo/Desktop/parkplus/parkplus-pms/controller/master/master_test.go:57 +0x485
testing.tRunner(0xc0000b6680, 0xd20c50)
        /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1439 +0x102
created by testing.(*T).Run
        /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1486 +0x35f
exit status 2
```

Comment: the panic happens in some code that you did not show `controller/master/master.go:31`. please add a [mre] to your question

Comment: @blackgreen if you can help now i have edited the code

Comment: you have to make clear in your question which one is line 31 in file `master.go`, as reported by your error trace. The crash is due to a nil pointer in some usage of the logrus logger. `logrus.(*Entry).Trace(...)` which is not initialized. This seems unrelated to the usage of gin test context

Comment: Hoping that problem is clear now

Comment: yes it is clear: you have to initialize your test dependencies, or redesign your unit tests to not rely on those you don't want to initialize